# Unable to log in to the application. Cannot read property of 'name' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, aspnetboilerplate

I am using AspNet Boilerplate V.1.0. Recently I am experiencing a difficulty with login. While logging in I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Smart_campus' of undefined
    at Object.abp.localization.localize (abp.js:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (abp.js:51)
    at Object.app.localize (helpers.js:6)
    at librarySettings.js:10
    at librarySettings.js:19
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at app.js:1383
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4708)
    at angular.js:4516
    at q (angular.js:322)
    at db (angular.js:4516)
    at c (angular.js:1777)
    at Ac (angular.js:1798)
    at fe (angular.js:1683)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:31018)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
```

app.js

```
    var appModule = angular.module("app", [
    "ui.router",
    'ngAnimate',
    "ngSanitize",
    "ui.bootstrap",
    'ui.utils',
    "ui.calendar",
    "ui.jq",
    'ui.grid',
    'ui.grid.pagination',
    'ui.grid.autoResize',
    'ui.grid.selection',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'angularFileUpload',
    'daterangepicker',
    'angularMoment',
    'frapontillo.bootstrap-switch',
    'abp',
    'ui.grid.moveColumns',
    'ui.grid.edit',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.grid.exporter',
    'ui.grid.cellNav',
    'ui.grid.validate',
    'ui.grid.resizeColumns',
    'ngInputModified'
]);
```

Smart_campus is our project name.
I am little confused where to check for the cause. Please help me with a solution or guidance.

Comment: Try clearing cache or try different browser

Comment: I tried both, tried on  mozilla,the error abp.localization.currentCulture is undefined is showing.

Comment: Do you have `import { AppComponentBase } from` `'@shared/common/app-component-base';` in your *.ts file?

Comment: If its there, then try deleting node_modulesfolder from angular directory and run `yarn` from command prompt on angular directory

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have entered duplicate key in your localizations

And try to localize a string with this code

```
 abp.localization.localize(yourLocalizationKey, "Smart_campus");
```

Comment: There are no duplication in the localization.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to some permission definition missed from AppAuthorizationProvider while code merge. The issue is solved when i place back the code.

```
var feeCollection = Fees.CreateChildPermission(AppPermissions.Pages_Masters_feeCollection, L("FeeCollection"), multiTenancySides: MultiTenancySides.Tenant);
            feeCollection.CreateChildPermission(AppPermissions.Pages_Masters_feeCollection_Create, L("CreateFeeCollection"), multiTenancySides: MultiTenancySides.Tenant);
            feeCollection.CreateChildPermission(AppPermissions.Pages_Masters_feeCollection_Edit, L("EditFeeCollection"), multiTenancySides: MultiTenancySides.Tenant);
            feeCollection.CreateChildPermission(AppPermissions.Pages_Masters_feeCollection_Cancel, L("CancelFeeCollection"), multiTenancySides: MultiTenancySides.Tenant);
```